# ActionController::UnknownFormat in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, respond-to

I have some product list where the user can add/remove items from their product list. I would like the mentioned iteration to be done via ajax with **format.js**

This is part of my input view where do i have the buttons to add/remove user items from product list:

```
.input-number__add
  = button_to '', product_add_path(id: product_item), remote: true, class: ''
.input-number__sub
  = button_to '', product_reduce_path(id: product_item), remote: true, class: ''
```

Here is my method where I add quantity in my item list in **ProductItemsController:**

```
  def add_quantity
    @product_item.quantity += 1 # increase 1 to the quantity

    if @product_item.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render partial: 'product_items/add_quantity' }
      end
    end
  end
```

What it does is go to 'product_items/add_quantity.js.erb' update the data and answer the request via js, but when it is reading the respond_to format.js I get the error:
**ActionController::UnknownFormat**, highlighting this line: **respond_to do |format|**

I saw in previous questions that give this solution respond_to :html, :json
but this doesn't work for me.

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: How do you call the controller function (e.g. which URL do you give)? The format to use is determined by the header and/ore "ending" where no ending defaults to HTML. tl;dr: Try to call it with `.js` at the end of the url.

Comment: @Cpt.Hook i missed the javascript_include_tag 'application', but thank you for your helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the route helpers `product_add_path` and `product_reduce_path` point to the `add_quantity` endpoint?

You can also try forcing the format:

```rb
product_add_path(id: product_item, format: :js)
```

**NOTE** Don't forget you need the `rails/ujs` library in order to use `remote: true` functionality

Comment: I'm sure and you are right, I missed the <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
and add jquery to worked me.

Thanks very much for your answer.